# Coloring text for all values of a table column

Tags: angularjs

I have a table component that I cannot change internally but instead I need to read the DOM element and color negative values in a specfic column red. 
So let´s say I have a table like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Person 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Address 1
        </td>
        <td>
            -2435
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Person 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Address 2
        </td>
        <td>
            432
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What would be an optimal way to read the table element and color the negative value of the amount for person 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to do it in Javascript; this is a snippet:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#mytable td').forEach(function(e) {
    if (!isNaN(e.innerText)) {
       e.style.color = 'red';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dqkeo9L/

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, are you getting your data to table from `$http` or from javascript `$scope` object? If so you can use simple `ng-class`
HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in data">
            <td>
               {{data.person}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{data.adres}}
            </td>
            <td ng-class="{negative: data.number < 0}">
                 {{data.number}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Your data:

```
 $scope.data = [{
   "person" : "person 1",
   "adress" : "Adress 1",
   "number": 2432
 },{
   "person" : "person 2",
   "adress" : "Adress 2",
   "number": -123
 }]
```

Style:

```
.negative {
    color: red;
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MZlUk7LsfYlNQtsC8xea?p=preview